# Android app on Kindle Fire HD errors

Tags: android, permissions, kindle

I am trying to run my android app on Kindle Fire HD.
here is the relevant bits of my build.gradle

```
android {
 compileSdkVersion 15
 buildToolsVersion "18.0.1"

 defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 15
 }
}

dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.0'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}
```

The app starts on both the device and emulator; but then I see the following logs

```
10-22 18:28:02.525    1132-1132/? D/AndroidRuntime﹕ >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
10-22 18:28:02.525    1132-1132/? D/AndroidRuntime﹕ CheckJNI is ON
10-22 18:28:03.574    1132-1132/? D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
10-22 18:28:03.664      121-141/system_process W/ActivityManager﹕ No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///data/local/tmp/com.myapp.app
10-22 18:28:03.824      121-141/system_process W/ActivityManager﹕ No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///data/local/tmp/com.myapp.app
10-22 18:28:04.246      121-122/system_process D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 347K, 43% free 13614K/23495K, paused 7ms+8ms
10-22 18:28:04.644      121-122/system_process D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 305K, 41% free 13888K/23495K, paused 7ms+9ms
10-22 18:28:04.984      121-122/system_process D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 657K, 41% free 13933K/23495K, paused 6ms+10ms
10-22 18:28:05.514      121-122/system_process D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 693K, 41% free 13934K/23495K, paused 7ms+12ms
10-22 18:28:05.894      121-122/system_process D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 701K, 41% free 13937K/23495K, paused 8ms+11ms
10-22 18:28:06.354      121-122/system_process D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 698K, 41% free 13912K/23495K, paused 6ms+11ms
10-22 18:28:06.664      121-141/system_process I/PackageManager﹕ Removing non-system package:com.myapp.app
10-22 18:28:06.664      121-136/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ Force stopping package com.myapp.app uid=10036
10-22 18:28:06.664      121-136/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ Killing proc         1091:com.myapp.app/10036: force stop
10-22 18:28:06.664      121-136/system_process W/ActivityManager﹕ Force removing ActivityRecord{41f90b28 com.myapp.app/.activities.Home}: app died, no saved state
10-22 18:28:06.695      121-136/system_process I/!SoftkeyBarManagerService﹕ [121,1000] refreshing softkeys
10-22 18:28:06.764      121-154/system_process W/InputDispatcher﹕ channel '415ea988 com.myapp.app/com.myapp.app.activities.Home (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
10-22 18:28:06.764      121-154/system_process E/InputDispatcher﹕ channel '415ea988 com.myapp.app/com.myapp.app.activities.Home (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
10-22 18:28:06.774      121-155/system_process I/InputReader﹕ Reconfiguring input devices.  changes=0x00000004
```

The app does not shutdown, but some functionality is not working, specifically network request.
The same app works on Samsung Galaxy SII.

I have seen similar questions, tried to fix permissions for /local/data; tried both emulator and device -- nothing helps. API level 15 should be the one Kindle 7.4.3 uses. At least I don't get any warnings while building the app.

Comment: Did you ever find a way around this?